# luaotfload: can't find font after updating font database

Tags: luaotfload

I have installed a new font `"MCS Diwany1 S_U adorned."` with xelatex there is no problem but with lualatex a file like this

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report} 
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont[Script=Arabic]{MCS Diwany1 S_U adorned.}

\begin{document}
\pardir TRT \textdir TRT     
أهلا  

\end{document}
```

Produces an error  `! fontspec error: "font-not-found"`. 
I tried to execute in the command line

```
luaotfload-tool --update --force
```

Without effect, and the result is

```
luaotfload | db : Unknown format: "", skipping.
```

Comment: FontForge complains loudly that the font name is invalid. I’ve seen it complain about other fonts that luatex manages to use, but there are *lots* of complaints when I open this font in FontForge.

Comment: I can't use this font with xelatex but at least the system can find the font.

Comment: Maybe renaming the font in FontForge would help?